# PDO array result as php variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, pdo

Is it possible to set a PDO result as a PHP $variable and use it outside the PDO query? Here is what I am trying to do:

SQL database contains:

```
names:
John
Peter
Allen
```

My code looks like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name",$username,$password);
$conn->query('SET NAMES UTF8');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

while($data = $q->fetch()){
$phpvar = "$data[names], ";
}

echo $phpvar;
```

The result I want from "echo $phpvar;" is:

```
John, Peter, Allen
```

Comment: Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `$phpvar` before the loop and concat the values to it.

```
$phpvar = '';
while($data = $q->fetch()){
    $phpvar .= "$data[names], ";
}
echo $phpvar;
```

Comment: AAAAAND we have a winner! This worked like a charm! :D Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

just declare a empty array and use it like below.

```
 $phpvar = array();

    while($data = $q->fetch()){
        array_push($phpvar, $data[names]);
    }
```

Comment: I just get "array" as a result when i try to "echo $phpvar;"

Comment: @CitronAutobot use `var_dump( $phpvar );`

Comment: @CitronAutobot if you want it as a string use `implode()` and for a json object you can use `json_encode()`  .

Answer (score 0):

PDO is throwing an object . So you have to do this on while loop after giving a null value in $phpvar , then you have to use rtrim()

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name",$username,$password);
$conn->query('SET NAMES UTF8');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$phpvar = '';

while($data = $q->fetchAll()){
$phpvar .= $data->names;
$phpvar .= ',';
}

echo rtrim($phpvar, ",");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't give any results at all. Just a blank screen. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: just Edited the answer .. if you still didn't get the deserved answer . I think your should check the error reporting is turned on or not  :-/

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme but as already mentioned, declare the variable that you wish to use later and populate in the loop

```
$phpvar=array();
while( $rs=$q->fetch() ) $phpvar[]=$rs->names;

print_r( $phpvar );
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that your query will fail and that you are setting `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which is the default and will give you duplicate results in your string, just use `implode()`.  It's also easier to just use `fetchAll()`:

```
$data = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$phpvar = implode(', ', $data);
```